# EF Core (.NET 5 + EFCore.BulkExtentions) : BulkInsert to SQL Server using the IncludeGraph not super fast

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-5, efcore.bulkextensions

I've constructed a multithreaded program that reads an 80GB XML file and inserts entities into SQL Server using EF Core bulk extensions.

The XML is a list of graphs that i want to insert as fast as possible.

I need to insert the objects as a graph to maintain their relations where i afterwords intend to run a series of cleanups to remove duplicates.

My main problem right now is that the

```
BulkInsert(entities, EncludeGraph = true)
```

isn't as fast as I want it to be.

- Inserting 1000 root elements takes a couple of seconds - but I have 11 million of them, turning into 15-20 hours.

The entities are created using model-first, where I've disabled the `CascadeDelete` option from the foreign key constraints. Each navigation property is automatically generated and creates a nonclustered index (which I suppose is OK).

- SQL Server: 2016, DB running on SQL Server 2014 compatibility level
- RecoveryModel is set to "Simple"

Any advice on how to improve the insert speed?

Comment: EF Core has no `BulkInsert`. It doesn't even make sense to talk about objects/graphs and `BULK INSERT` in the same sentence. BULK INSERT refers to a very specific way of *inserting rows to a single table* with minimal logging (instead of logging individual rows, only entire data pages are logged). This is performed through the `BULK IINSERT` command, `bcp` tool or `SqlBulkCopy` class. It makes no sense to talk about objects and graphs in that context. `I have 11M rows` don't use an ORM then. ETL has no objects/entities, or rather, its entities are `Row`, `Column`, `Mapping` and `Transform`

Comment: If you can handle the data you want as an `IEnumerable<T>` you can use FastMebmer's `[ObjectReader](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member#ever-needed-an-idatareader) to wrap the enumerable with a `DbDataReader` and pass it to SqlBulkCopy. You'll have to configure the batch and transaction settings to avoid flooding the transaction log too - even with minimal logging, inserting 11M rows will take up that much space in the transaction log if you use a single transaction. It's better to insert into a staging table using a (relatively) small batch size and move the new data to the target later

Comment: Hi Panagiotis. I forgot to include that i use EFCore.BulkExtensions in the title and text, but remembered to use it in the Tags.

Comment: This doesn't change the fact that ORMs are the wrong tool for ETL. You have pure data manipulation, not objects with behaviors. ORMs deal with single object graphs at a time, not a stream of rows the way SqlBulkCopy does. Or SSIS, or any other ETL tool.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, and again. With `linq2db` we are doing ETL very often. If you work only with EF, this does not mean than ORM cannot do ETL tasks.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv and once again, what linq2db does is convert objects to rows and use SqlBulkCopy. I do the same with Dapper and FastMember's ObjectReader when I feel lazy. You can't do anything that the database doesn't allow you to do. You can't execute any query that can't be translated to SQL. You can't do bulk imports without using SqlBulkCopy, or MySqlBulkCopy, or PostreSQL's COPY. As always, the more extra stuff you do over the stream of rows, the worse performance is, especially for millions of rows. Again, you need to work with a stream, not a graph

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, sure not with graph. You are talking about obvious things.

Comment: Please add a sample of your XML to the question, and the DDL of the target tables.  Bypassing the Entity Layer, and going from XML to SqlBulkCopy is going to be the fastest.  And finding a way to use client-side key assignment (like with a SEQUENCE) may also be critical.  An 80GB XML file is way out of the target scale for EF.

Comment: @MartinKirk are there any obvious (business) key fields in the data? Post an example. If there are, you may be able to insert each "type" into a different staging table with `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` columns, and fix up relations afterwards. How do you load the data? If you use eg an XmlReader you may be able to "push" different types to different sinks concurrently using, eg a Channel

Comment: @MartinKirk if, on the other hand, you deserialize the entire file into memory before trying to insert it, it would actually be better to load the XML into a DataSet then insert each table to the database with SqlBulkCopy. You're loading everything in memory anyway which isn't very efficient. Might as well use a form that's easy to insert.

Comment: I'll update the Answer with a description of my current, rather fast solution.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the Sourcecode of EFCore.BulkInsert it's pretty obvious that the way that it inserts a whole graph of objects, is by first bulk inserting all the parents - then retrieve the ID's, update the 1st level childrens parentid then bulk insert them etc until the final leaf nodes.

This is suboptimal since it takes several roundtrips to complete a medium nested graph.

The only way i can i imagine making this faster, is by doing identi-insert by manually creating the Identity values outside of SQL and then traverse the graph and update all child elements with their parent id.

THEN bulk insert using identity-insert without any roundtrips.

UPDATE:

I made it all work quite nicely. Inserting about 30.000 rows pr second (50-60MB/s SQL write speed) and it finishes the 80GB XML file in about 45 minutes. Which is quite acceptable compared to the previous 12+ hour process.

I've made a series of threads that does single tasks:

Thread 1. Read from Zipped XML Archive into a ConcurrentQueue

Thread 2. Scan the Queue for Start-Stop elements. Merging them using StringBuilder into ConcurrentQueue

Thread 3. Remove namespace from XML-entity and add to ConcurrentQueue

Thread 4. Deserialize XML into Object and add to ConcurrentQueue

Thread 5. Create Lists of 1000 Objects and add to ConcurrentQueue<List>

Thread 6. Use GraphUtil.GetTopologicallySortedGraph from [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions) to split the object into List of Entity Types and insert to DB using BulkInsert ( KeepIdentity=true )

```
var grp = GraphUtil.GetTopologicallySortedGraph(db, list).GroupBy(g => g.Entity.GetType());

foreach (var typecollection in grp)
{
    var entityClrType = typecollection.Key;

    var sublist = typecollection.Select(s => s.Entity).ToList();

    ObjectCount += sublist.Count;

    db.BulkInsert(sublist, config, type: entityClrType);
}
```

Note: When Deserializing the XML's their ID's are created:

```
private static int _EntityID;

public Entity()
{
     EntityID= ++_EntityID;
}
```

Note: I'm using EFCore Codefirst mechanics, which automatically handles all navigation properties and their relation ID - very important ! - updating the child ID automatically ensures the parent relation.

Note: I'm running 1 Deserializer (can't run more than one because of static identity counters) and 6 BulkInserter threads

Comment: The way to make this faster is to just not use an ORM. You don't have any Objects to Map